Rich-text inline (intra-cell) formatting in Excel Office Script
Is there any way to add rich-text formatting within a single cell in a Microsoft Excel Office Script?
It's doable non-programmatically within MS Excel — e.g. press F2 to edit within a cell, highlight one word, press Ctrl+B:



It's also doable in VBA and Google Sheets scripts.
Is this possible in Office Scripts or is it simply a missing feature at the moment?

AFAIK, Office Scripts doesn't support it.
